# Resource not found exception at setDropDownBackgroundColor

Tags: android, android-resources, android-background

I'm trying to set a DropDown Background Color for a autocompleteTextView, because the standart Values seem to be different during different Android Versions. For example, everything works fine starting with android 3.2, but previous Versions seem to not accept the `android:textColor="@color/black"` in the xml, cause it is not working for me. Android 2.3 for example just shows the items in the list and the ones I picked in white, which isn't working for me, cause the background is white too. So I decided to change the background Color determing on the android version using this:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        // Do something for Honeycomb and above versions
        //everything is right
    } else{
        // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
        box_Kurs.setDropDownBackgroundResource(Color.BLUE);
        box_Teacher.setDropDownBackgroundResource(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

But when I start my app it crashes and shows resource not found exception:

```
11-19 15:40:17.225: E/AndroidRuntime(450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shr.khg/com.shr.khg.AddActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff0000ff
```

What am I doing wrong? I alread cleaned my project since that what other people suggested. Or is there any easier way to deal with my issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [`setDropDownBackgroundResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownBackgroundResource%28int%29) is expecting the id of the `Color` resource `Drawable`, not an `int` that defines a `Color`. If you look at the `Exception` you can see that Android is trying to find a component with id `#0xff0000ff`, this is the hex code for a completely opaque blue which is the value of `Color.BLUE`

Answer (score 0):

Replce these two lines:

```
box_Kurs.setDropDownBackgroundResource(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
box_Teacher.setDropDownBackgroundResource(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
```